# NullPointerException on Adapter notifyDataSetChanged(). What do I need to do?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

So I have an AsyncTask class to handle populating my `RecyclerView`. It works well but when it needs to be refreshed then it crashes with a `NullPointerException`. I kind of know why but then I can't do it because I am creating a new `object` and adding it to my `list`.

This is my code:

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
                userslist.clear();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    ...
                    UsersData usersData = new UsersData(var1, var2);
                    userslist.add(UsersData);
                }
                cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Culprit line, despite the list being deleted and added again in the try block
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I suspect is it something to do with the `userslist`.

This is my error logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at lukazs.newapp.UserInfo$GetUserList.onPostExecute(UserInfo.java:218)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:741)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:197)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:654)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
```

EDIT: This is the method call where I populate the `recyclerview`:

```
public void populate(){
    GetUserList getUserList = new GetUserList();
    getUserList.execute();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    populate();
    }
```

This is where `cAdapter` is initialised, in `onCreate` method:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter cAdapter;
ArrayList<UserDetailsProvider> userslist = new ArrayList<UserDetailsProvider>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    populateRecyclerList();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleMusic);
    cAdapter = new UserDefinedAdapter(userslist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are clearing the arraylist in which the adapter is attached to. If you clear the arraylist then you need to reattach it. But at the same time I don't know why you are clearing the list. Just do notifyDataSetChanged();. Plus the only code you need on the onPostExecute function is cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I removed `list.clear()` and it is still crashing

Comment: Post your adapter implementation.

Comment: I suspect its my populate method, please see OP

Comment: Im using `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Comment: Your `cAdapter` member variable is null.

Comment: Please include more detail in your code. We cannot see where `cAdapter` is initialized, so we assume it is null since that is where you say the Exception is

Answer (score 1):

My pattern for adapter,

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
       private List<YOUR CLASS> data = new ArrayList<>();
       Context context;

       public MyAdapter(Context context){
             this.context = context;
       }

       public void addAll(List<YOUR CLASS> data) {
             this.data.addAll(data);
             this.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }

       public void clear() {
             data.clear();
             this.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
           //Other Methods of Adapter
}
```

in your onCreate() method, just initialize an adapter to recyclerview.

```
cAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
```

in asynctask,

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try {
            cAdapter.clear();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                ...
                UsersData usersData = new UsersData(var1, var2);
                userslist.add(usersData);
            }
            cAdapter.addAll(userslist); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great and all, but where is `cAdapter` initialized? That is what the problem in the code is

Comment: in your onCreate() method. with adapter's constructor. wait i am editing my answer for you.

Comment: Right, in `onCreate` of the `Activity` or `Fragment`, then how does it get to the `AsyncTask`? That is what I am trying to get you to show

Comment: `cAdapter` is still uninitialized in the `onPostExecute`. What if the `AsyncTask` is not an inner class?

Answer (score 0):

first get adapter from listview then update

```
ListAdapter cAdapter=listview.getAdapter();
cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```